# Xcode 10.2.1 Simulator Not Loading Settings or Other Built-In Apps

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode10.2

When I open the Simulator "Settings" on the Home Screen they open and then crash before loading.  The same thing happens when I open other built-in apps like Safari.  Otherwise, the simulator behaves normally and I am able to run test apps I've created.

A restart of Xcode, Simulators, and computer didn't fix the issue.  Erasing all contents and settings didn't work.  Starting up different simulators doesn't work.

I just updated Mac OS to Mojave 10.14.4, which may or may not be playing a role.

Short of re-installing Xcode is there anything else I can try?

UPDATE: I just tried a re-install and it didn't fix the simulator either, so now I've no idea what to do.  Hopefully this get fixed in a future Xcode update?

Comment: Hi Ben, i'm using the same versions and everything is fine for me, i think you should re-install the Xcode and try, seems there is no other way to fix the issue.

Comment: Yep, I went for the re-install.  Unfortunately, that didn't fix the problem so now I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: I would suggest filing a bug report with Apple.

Comment: Good idea.  Just did so.  Thanks for the encouragement!